# How to make user input in Python 3

Tags: python, user-input

I want to create a program that will say correct or incorrect when a user types down a answer.

I tried using Python storing variables to solve the problem but to no avail

The code is a bit like this

```
    question1 = input ("Type down a password!")
    if input = "bannanas"
      print('Sucess!')

else print("ohhhhh")
```

But the terminal says

```
File "main.py", line 2
    if input = "bannanas"
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`enter code here`
```

Comment: Try `if question1 == "bannanas"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the comparison operator, `==`, instead of the assignment operator (`=`):

```
question1 = input("Type down a password!")

if input == "bannanas": print('Success!')

else: print("ohhhhh")
```

You also have a few other syntatical errors, like missing colons (which I added).

Comment: No problem! If the answer solved your question, it's good practice to upvote and accept. The latter also grants you a small rep bonus :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code must be like below:

```
question1 = input("Type down a password!")
if question1 == 'bannanas':
    print('Sucess!')
else:
    print('ohhhhh')
```